# D3.js force layout: How to isolate node groups?

Tags: graph, d3.js, simulation, data-visualization, force-layout

**What I'm trying to achieve?**

I would like to have groups of nodes, in a tree-like structure where each root is either the main root, or is a descendant of a leaf from another tree.

Generating what you see below is easy, but what I'd really like to see is complete circles around each root. However, since the nodes are repelling each other the below gaps are present between each cluster. *I assume the solution involves ignoring the repulsion caused by charges between leaves coming from different roots*.

[image]

**My ideas**

- Set some sort of radius around each root which repels other nodes in all directions beyond that radius, allowing the leaves to be circular within it
- Use linkDistances and linkStrengths to somehow arrange the clusters in a way that they do not interact significantly

**Is this possible?**

Other than my vague ideas, I really have no clue how to do this!

From reading the D3 docs, I found that unlike the dynamic linkDistance and linkStrength methods, node charge manipulations seem to be universal:

```
"All nodes are assumed to be infinitesimal points with equal charge and mass."
```

If this statement is true, can one of you guys please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you would approach it, but I found an example in which clusters have charge only within themselves and nodes don't interact with different ones: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804889

Comment: drag bubbles to see it in action

Answer (score 0):

I'm think the beginning of an answer might be in this stackoverflow question, [Space out nodes evenly around root node in D3 force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639270/space-out-nodes-evenly-around-root-node-in-d3-force-layout)

Do know that *is* possible to make each node's charge dependent on some attribute of same. 
  Try it with something like

```
   .charge(function(d) { console.log(d); //you'll see this brings up the nodes
   if (d.something == onething) { 
      return    -1300;} 
   else { 
      return -100; } 
    })
```

As the linked-to answer mentions, you'll almost certainly have to experiment with "friction" and "linkDistance." Don't be afraid of trial and error--I at least have been intermittently dealing with this kind of issue for a few months now, and haven't yet found a "general" solution.