# Space out nodes evenly around root node in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

*I am just starting on D3, so if anyone has any general suggestions on thing I might not be doing correctly/optimally, please let me know :)*

I am trying to create a Force Directed graph with the nodes spaced out evenly (or close enough) around the center root node (noted by the larger size).

Here's an example of the layout I'm trying to achieve (I understand it won't be the same every time):
[image]

I have the following graph:

```
var width = $("#theVizness").width(),
    height = $("#theVizness").height();

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#ff0000", "#fff000", "#ff4900"]);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("#theVizness").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var loading = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "loading")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", height / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Loading...");

/*
ForceDirectData.json
{
    "nodes":[
      {"name":"File1.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File2.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File3.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File4.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File5.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File6.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File7.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File8.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File8.exe","colorGroup":0},
      {"name":"File9.exe","colorGroup":0}
    ],
    "links":[
      {"source":1,"target":0,"value":10},
      {"source":2,"target":0,"value":35},
      {"source":3,"target":0,"value":50},
      {"source":4,"target":0,"value":50},
      {"source":5,"target":0,"value":65},
      {"source":6,"target":0,"value":65},
      {"source":7,"target":0,"value":81},
      {"source":8,"target":0,"value":98},
      {"source":9,"target":0,"value":100}
    ]
}
*/

d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5772230/ForceDirectData.json", function (error, json) {
    var nodes = json.nodes;
    force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(json.links)
        .linkDistance(function (d) {
            return d.value * 1.5;
        })
        .charge(function(d){
            var charge = -500;
            
            if (d.index === 0) charge = 0;
            
            return charge;
        })
        .friction(0.4);
    
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(json.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")              
        .style("stroke-width", 1);
    
        var files = svg.selectAll(".file")
        .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "file")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.colorGroup);
        });
    var totalNodes = files[0].length;
    
    files.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
    
    force.start();
    for (var i = totalNodes * totalNodes; i > 0; --i) force.tick();

    
    nodes[0].x = width / 2;
    nodes[0].y = height / 2;
    
    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
    
    files.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("class", function(d){
            var classString = "file"
            
            if (d.index === 0) classString += " rootFile";
            
            return classString;
        })
        .attr("r", function(d){
            var radius = 10;
            
            if (d.index === 0) radius = radius * 2;
            
            return radius;
        });
    force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    files.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
    
    loading.remove();
    
  });
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/w5Ld9tup/)

I have already tried getting close to this with the `charge()` method. I thought giving every node besides the root node a higher charge would accomplish this, but it did not.

### *What can I do to have the child nodes evenly spaced around the root node?*

Comment: Compute the positions of the nodes yourself. The force layout is not suitable to achieve exactly this.

Comment: That's actually a great idea! Then I have full control over all the points in the locations.

Comment: I agree with Lars. Notice too that this doesn't imply that you'd get rid of `links`, which is still a useful construct. And when it comes to updating the nodes, you might as well do it by setting their `x` and `y` just like the force layout would. Of course this way is compatible with your existing rendering code, but it's also compatible with force layout. So if needed, you can toggle modes between your own layout and the force layout.

Comment: Hey @FillipPeyton do you happen to have a copy of the original json used here? Seems to have been nuked from dropbox.

Comment: @ReidBlomquist I do not. Sorry :(

Comment: Its a shame this nice idea is not being helpful for many others without the json!

Comment: I _just_ found the data (I believe). Wasn't able to test it at the moment, but added the structure to the code above. Hope this helps some!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, force layout is a perfect tool for situations like yours.

You just need to change a little initialization of the layout, like this

```
force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .charge(function(d){
        var charge = -500;
        if (d.index === 0) charge = 10 * charge;
        return charge;
    });
```

and voila

[image]

*Explanation*. I had to remove settings for `friction` and `linkDistance` since they affected placement in a bad way. The `charge` for root node is 10 times larger so that all other nodes are dominantly pushed away from the root. Other nodes also repel each other, and the perfect symmetry is achieved at the end, as a result.

Jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4L3y0Lm2/).

---

I see from your code that you attempted to affect distance from the root node and other nodes by utilizing `linkDistance` that is dependant on data. However, it might be better (although counter-intuitive) to use `linkStrength` for that purpose, like this

```
force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .linkStrength(function (d) {
        return d.value / 100.0;
    })
    .charge(function(d){
        var charge = -500;
        if (d.index === 0) charge = 10 * charge;
        return charge;
    });
```

but you need to experiment.

---

For centering and fixing the root node, you can use this

```
nodes[0].fixed = true;
nodes[0].x = width / 2;
nodes[0].y = height / 2;
```

but before initialization of layout, like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yyxa3e8q/) Jsfiddle.

Comment: This is a very good solution. The links look like the all have a very similar length, so I'm testing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/b5a3pv8y/) with exaggerated link lengths. It works!

Comment: I just need to figure out how to center this bad boy and I'll be set.

Comment: @FillipPeyton I updated the answer with centering info.

Comment: Bingo. Accepted.
I'm still going to look into generating this as a simple draw to the canvas via D3, but this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I am really glad it helped, @FillipPeyton !

Comment: That's a great solution thanks! But what's the deal with the '===' in (d.index === 0)?

Comment: Also, while this works great when arranging a limited number of nodes in in one circle around the root, does it work well with an increased number of nodes where nodes must be arranged in layers (concentric circles) with the root at the center and evenly spaced out?

Comment: Does anyone have a copy of this json? Seems dropbox nuked it

Comment: @ReidBlomquist Json is embedded as a comment in the code in the question, you can reconstruct it easily.